How to allow users to edit survey answers after submission
How to allow user edit survey answers after submission? After a user reviews all the answers in a survey, I want to allow them to edit them.
I tried already adding access right:
<record id="group_survey_editors" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Survey Editors</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_human_resources"/>
</record>

And record rule:
[('state', 'in', ['done'])]

But no luck.
